# Using SUM function in query on eliminated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table A in `PostgreSQL`:

```
idMain  idSub    quantity
49;     83604;   3000.0000
49;     84361;   16000.0000
49;     84268;   30
47;     84268;   10.0000
```

I have a query that choose a `idMain` and present data about it. I need to add another column for this query so that it will `SUM` `quantity` of all `idMain` (exclude my own `quantity`)  where `idSub`   is the same.

The desired data is:

```
idMain  idSub    quantity      newcolumn
49;     83604;   3000.0000         0                //no other 83604 so 0
49;     84361;   16000.0000        0                //no other 84361 so 0
49;     84268;   30                10.0000          //other 84268 is 10.000 (and don't count my own 30)
```

First I did:

```
select idMain,IdSub,coalesce( SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY idSub) - quantity ,0)
from A
where idMain=49
```

Notice that the query on the `WHERE` remove the `idMain=47` so what I did doesn't work since it doesn't SUM the `idMain=47`

Then I tried:

```
select idMain,IdSub,(SELECT coalesce( SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY a2.idSub) - a2.quantity,0) from A a2 where a2.idSub=a.idSub) 
from A
where idMain=49
```

But that also doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to get it? it seems like I'm very close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's answer returns the correct result, but this will first calculate the Group Sum for all rows before applying the filter on idMain.

Your 2nd query is also almost right (and should apply the filter first), you just need to remove the OVER and use a simple Scalar Subquery instead:

```
select idMain,IdSub,quantity,
  coalesce((SELECT SUM(quantity) 
            from A a2 
            where a2.idSub=a.idSub) - quantity,0) as new column
from A
where idMain=49;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is almost right.  You just need to use a subquery (or CTE):

```
select t.*
from (select idMain, IdSub,
             coalesce(SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY idSub) - quantity, 0
                     ) as newcol
      from A
     ) t
where idMain = 49;
```

In your version, it does the filtering *before* calculating the `sum()`.  That isn't what you want, so a subquery to the rescue.